# Add title to a SAS dataset

Tags: sas

I hope that you can help me out with a question.

After creating a summarizing table (using proc summary, proc means etc.), I would like to add a title to the dataset. It's not the easiest thing to remember sample restrictions etc. so it would help a lot to be able to add a title, for example: *"Mean income (note: incomes < $1000 have been excluded)"*.

An obvious way of doing this is to create another dataset...

```
data title;
length title $100;
title = "Mean income (note: incomes < $1000 have been excluded)";
run;
```

...and then combine this with the summarizing table. But is there a standard procedure to simply add a title while creating the table?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understood correctly, what you want to accomplish is called Label of SAS dataset.
You can add label to your dataset when creating it by using dataset option `LABEL`.
You should be able to use it anywhere you can use dataset options and you're creating dataset, e.g.:

```
data title (label="Mean income (note: incomes < $1000 have been excluded)");
length var1 8;
run;

proc sql;
create table title2 (label="Title in SQL") as select * from title
;
quit;

proc sort data=title out = title_sorted (label="Title Sorted");
by var1;
run;
```

Or add/modify title later via PROC DATASETS:

```
proc datasets lib=WORK nodetails nolist;
modify title (label="New title");
quit;
```

Comment: Thanks! It seemed to work well as long as I'm working in SAS.

I forgot to mention that I often export my tables to Excel and that's why I would like to include the title as a row in the dataset.

Is there a way to make sure that the title follows the dataset when I'm exporting it to Excel?

Comment: @Johan No, going to Excel you'll likely lose it (depending on how you go to excel, but if you're using PROC EXPORT, you can't take along things like that).  You can if you use one of the ODS options (9.2/3 `ODS TAGSETS.EXCELXP`, 9.4 `ODS EXCEL`), but that's a different process and at least a somewhat different result (especially with TAGSETS).

Comment: @Joe: Ok, thanks for your answer. Seems like I have to keep adding the title in the way that I've always been doing it.